Graph API error 131049 This message was not delivered to maintain healthy ecosystem engagement
Through this facebook developers article and this supporting article I understand that there are certain limitations on sending marketing templates. Everytime a user replies in an open marketing conversation (i.e. If a user responds to a marketing template) we are allowed to send one more marketing template.
In my case, I am sending user a template lets say template_A, when he interacts with that template he should get a text message and another template, template_B. Which, according to the articles, is possible. But the user is only getting the text message and not template_B, with console stating that

131049 This message was not delivered to maintain healthy ecosystem
engagement.

Also, this is not happening with all the numbers. Some of them can use the app properly. Am I reading something wrong here? Are there any kind of other limitations that can be causing this issue?
